# AWS EMR HadoopJarStepConfig step function arguments not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, sh, amazon-emr, aws-java-sdk

I am working on adding step functions to AWS EMR which will add an extra line in "crontab -e". As I don't want to append directly to the crontab file as I might have duplicate cron jobs, I am fetching all the existing jobs, adding the new job and removing the duplicate like so:

```
HadoopJarStepConfig turnOnCronJob1 = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                .withJar("command-runner.jar")
                .withArgs("bash", "-c", "\"(crontab -l; echo '*/5 * * * * /mnt/" + scriptName + "')", "|", "sort -u", "|", "crontab -\"");
```

But, the function is failing with an exit code 1. I have ran this command directly on my EMR cluster as:

```
hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-jars/command-runner.jar bash -c "(crontab -l; echo '*/5 * * * * /mnt/reademrpushmetrics.sh') | sort -u | crontab -"
```

And, this is working fine with no errors. I have tried following HadoopJarStepConfig, but they are not working either:

```
HadoopJarStepConfig turnOnCronJob2 = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                .withJar("command-runner.jar")
                .withArgs("(crontab -l; echo '*/5 * * * * /mnt/" + scriptName + "')", "|", "sort -u", "|", "crontab -");
HadoopJarStepConfig copyOldCronTabToNew1 = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                .withJar("command-runner.jar")
                .withArgs("crontab -l", ">", "/mnt/newCronTab");
HadoopJarStepConfig copyOldCronTabToNew2 = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                .withJar("command-runner.jar")
                .withArgs("crontab", "-l", ">", "/mnt/newCronTab");
HadoopJarStepConfig copyOldCronTabToNew3 = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                .withJar("command-runner.jar")
                .withArgs("bash", "-c", "\"crontab -l > /mnt/newCronTab\"");
```

The last three code config file was an alternative method that I was trying by creating a new "newCronTab" file and storing my new crontab jobs before adding all of them to the "crontab -e". The last config actually gives a different exitCode error 127, and not 1 like others as shown here:
[image]
[image]
All of these command seems to work if I run them directly on EMR cluster with hadoop command. I am 99% sure that the problem is in the arguments that I am passing with not escaping certain characters properly. If anyone has encountered this, how did you fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in the arguments of `HadoopJarStepConfig`, you are not supposed to add an extra double quotes. So, the correct format for `turnOnCronJob1` and `copyOldCronTabToNew3` looks like:

```
HadoopJarStepConfig turnOnCronJob1 = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                    .withJar("command-runner.jar")
                    .withArgs("bash", "-c", "(crontab -l; echo '*/5 * * * * /mnt/" + scriptName + "') | sort -u | crontab -");
HadoopJarStepConfig copyOldCronTabToNew3 = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                    .withJar("command-runner.jar")
                    .withArgs("bash", "-c", "crontab -l > /mnt/newCronTab");
```

Also, things to note is that `turnOnCronJob2` and `copyOldCronTabToNew1` config arguments are invalid ways of passing arguments. But, `copyOldCronTabToNew2` config arguments are correct.